# Facebook Connect button redirects to canvas page instead of closing the popup window

Tags: facebook, authentication, button

I am trying to have a connect button on my site. Once the user has clicked the Facebook login button, the popup will ask the user to enter the authentication detail and the parent window will either redirect or refresh the page and the login button will become a logout button.

My problem is when a user clicks the connect button from the popup, the popup page redirects to my canvas page rather than closes the popup instead.

Comment: Please provide some code so we can inspect what is happening.  Also, did you specify a 'onlogin' attribute to your fb:login-button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many people have posted this issue, if you have done everything else right, the reason for this is xd_receiver file was not read by the fb.

You need to make sure that where your fb connect button is, you specify the correct path to xd_receiver.html file somewhere on bottom of that page. Something like below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    FB.init("your api key here", "xd_receiver.htm");
</script>
```

It is even better and easier to put the xd_receiver file on your site's root folder and specify it with full domain url like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    FB.init("your api key here", "http://www.yoursite.com/xd_receiver.htm");
</script>
```

Comment: Hey Sarfraz, do you have a list of those questions that people have asked about this?  I'm getting a `this._opts.channelUrl is null` javascript error upon logging in.  The site doesn't redirect, but if I manually refresh I discover that I'm logged in.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample of facebook connect, login and logout, works very well,
Also make sure you add your site url under your app settings -> Website - > Site URL:[image: Your Site URL]

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"> 
        <head> 
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
            <title>Facebook Connect Sample</title> 
        </head> 
        <body> 
            <div id="fb-root"></div> 
            <script> 
            window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                FB.init({
                  appId  : 'YOUR APP ID',
                  status : true, // check login status
                  cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
                  xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
                });

            /* All the events registered */
            FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
                // do something on login
                login();
            });
            FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
                // do something on logout
                logout();
            });

            FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                if (response.session) {
                    // logged in and connected user, someone you know
                    login();
                }
            });
        };

      /* Loading the JS SDK Asynchronously - Refer: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/ */
      (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script');
        e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        e.async = true;
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
      }());

    function login(){
        window.location = "http://google.com"; // Redirect to Another Page.

        /* Show User's Name 
        FB.api('/me', function(response) {
            document.getElementById('login').style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById('login').innerHTML = response.name + " succsessfully logged in!";
        });
        */
    }
    function logout(){ 
        document.getElementById('login').style.display = "none";
    }
    </script> 
    <p><fb:login-button autologoutlink="true"></fb:login-button></p> 
        <div id="login" style ="display:none"></div> 
</body> 
</html>
```